# Replace N/As in a data.table join

Tags: r, data.table

When joining data tables I'd like to be able to replace NA values that aren't matched. Is there a way to do this all in one line? I've provided my own two line solution but I imagine there must be a cleaner way. It would also help when I'm using it for multiple variables not to require a line for each.

```
dt1[dt2, frequency.lrs := lr, on = .(joinVariable)]
dt1[is.na(frequency.lrs), frequency.lrs := 1]
```

Comment: what is `out`? you don't define it

Comment: Sorry fixed that now

Comment: This proposed change might make the one-liner possible: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/857#issuecomment-427203852

Answer (score 4):

You could create (and fill fill) the column `frequency.lrs` with value 1 before joining with dt2, and then use the update join to replace frequency.lrs on matched rows only.

```
dt1[, frequency.lrs := 1][dt2, frequency.lrs := lr, on = .(joinVariable)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

```
dt1[, VAL := 
    dt2[dt1, on=.(ID), replace(VAL, is.na(VAL), 1)]
]
```

output:

```
   ID VAL
1:  1   3
2:  2   1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(ID=1:2)
dt2 <- data.table(ID=1, VAL=3)
```